# Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.9, model, module

I have custom module **lenses** which is working well, but when I try to access data of lenses model it gives me an error. This is my code

```
 $Lenses= Mage::getModel('lenses/lenses');
  foreach($Lenses as $Lens)
  {
     $Lens->getData('description'); //or
     $Lens->getDescription();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to iterate object which is not a collection. You may try following instead:

```
$Lenses= Mage::getModel('lenses/lenses')->getCollection();
foreach($Lenses as $Lens)
{
    $Lens->getData('description'); //or
    $Lens->getDescription();
}
```

If you want to access data of single object, you may do following:

```
$Lens = Mage::getModel('lenses/lenses')->load(12) // load by id
$Lens->getData('description'); //or
$Lens->getDescription();
```